# VBA: Subroutine recognizes numbers in array, but can't output them?

Tags: vba, excel, vector, matrix-multiplication

I've just started learning VBA, and I've been playing around with a subroutine that would take a random length column of numbers starting at cell `A2`, and create and output its transpose using `application.transpose()` somewhere else. This is my code.

```
Sub boxmatrix()

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Select

Dim x()
Dim xt()

Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
n = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

ReDim x(1 To n)
ReDim xt(1 To n)

Dim range1 As Range    
Dim range2 As Range
Dim range3 As Range

Set range1 = Range("A2").CurrentRegion
Set range2 = Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(1, n + 2))

x = range1

xt = Application.Transpose(x)
range2.Value = xt

Debug.Print (x(1)) <--- THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS

End Sub
```

I've created the code that does accomplish those two things, but I've noticed that I can't do anything else, like multiply these two vectors to create a matrix, because my array `x()` isn't recognized as having numbers??

Any time I try to reference `x(#)`, I get an error, whereas referencing `xt(#)` works perfectly fine, which is annoying as `xt(#)` was populated from the numbers supposedly in `x(#)` in the first place?

Comment: `x` will be two-dimensional (first dimension is rows, second dimension is columns [which will be `1 To 1` if it is a single column]) after the `x = range1` statement, so use `Debug.Print x(1, 1)`

Comment: If you use the Locals Window as you step through your code, you will be able to see the changes to the variables as you execute each statement.

Comment: Further no what @YowE3K has noted about *x* now being a 2D array, the `ReDim x(1 To n)` and `ReDim xt(1 To n)` are useless since you rewrite the x array's dimensions when you assign values from the the worksheet cells and rewrite xt's dimensions when you assign it the transposed values from the second rank of x. Note: use a Watch in hte VBE on each array.

Comment: @Jeeped Your comment pre-dates my answer, but I **swear** I was writing that!! :D

Comment: Further, you are being very specific about teh sizes of the ranges/arrays. You should be writing code that won't matter what size they are. Example: `Cells(1, 3).resize(ubound(xt, 1), ubound(xt, 2)) = xt`

Comment: Can you describe what is happening with these resize(ubound....  bits?

Comment: You are using `range2` as a predefined target size which may or may not be the size of the array. By choosing a single cell as the target then resizing it to the **U**pper **Bound**aries of each **rank** in the array, you cannot have more or less than the correct number of cells to receive the array's values. IOW, it **has** to be a perfect fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `CurrentRegion` for cell A2 is just other cells in column A, then the statement

```
ReDim x(1 To n)
```

is creating a `Variant` array which is one-dimensional, with bounds `1 To n`.  But your subsequent statement

```
x = range1
```

is replacing that variable with a `Variant` array which is two-dimensional, with the first dimension having bounds `1 To n`, and the second dimension having bounds `1 To 1`.

So, to access the first row and first (and only) column, you can use:

```
Debug.Print x(1, 1)
```

Comment: But would there be a way to convert x into a normal 1D vector as intended, or prevent this warping into 2D's in the first place? Thank you for your help thus far, though.

Comment: The `Application.Transpose` command will convert a two-dimensional array that is `1 To n, 1 To 1` so that it is a one-dimensional array of `1 To n`.  (And, if your original array is a `1 To 1, 1 To n` array, e.g. multiple cells in a single row, `Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(myArray))` will convert that to a `1 To n` - the first `Transpose` converting it to a `1 To n, 1 To 1` and the second `Transpose` converting it to the `1 To n`.)  But one thing to be careful of ... `Application.Transpose` will only work up to a certain size.

Comment: fwiw, just to keep terminology clear, in a 2D array the 'dimensions' are called **ranks**. So with `x = range("a1:c5").value` the 'rows' would be the first rank and the 'columns' would be the second rank. `debug.print lbound(x, 1) & ":" & ubound(x, 1)` would print `1:5` in the Immediate window and `debug.print lbound(x, 2) & ":" & ubound(x, 2)` would print `1:3`.

Comment: @Jeeped Well there's my bit of trivia learned for today - I hadn't known that :)  (Or perhaps I had known it, but I had forgotten.  That seems to be a common event these days.  I'll have probably forgotten it again by tomorrow too :( )

Comment: I ended up going with the double transpose function to get my code to work, which I never would have guessed since I had already tried transposing it again to no avail. @Jeeped Thanks for that info, in both of your comments, it will come in handy!

Thanks for both of your help!